# Azure functions pass ILogger reference to the shared library lead to Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions'

Tags: azure, nuget, azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime

I have a Azure function that passes ILogger reference to my shared library

List of NuGet Package installed on AzureFunctionProject 
**Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions v5.0.0

Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions v3.0.11**

List of NuGet Package installed on SharedProject are
**Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions v5.0.0**

Function Runtime fail to Start with following error

> System.Private.CoreLib: Could not load file or assembly
> 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions, Version=5.0.0.0,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. The system cannot
> find the file specified.

The function application works locally using func.exe but when i deploy to Azure function runtime, it fails to start with above error.

Do i need to include additional NuGet Packages that supports Logging.Abstractions in both azure functions and shared library project?

Comment: Check if https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools/issues/2304 helps

Answer (score 0):

You can directly send the Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions .dll file to function app on azure(You can first use something like kudu or ftp to check the content of function app on azure, compare with the content of function app on local.).